# Save FTP servers in Coda

Tags: macos, coda

I've started using Coda because I just got a new Mac, and I want to know if it is possible to save FTP servers, since I'm regularly using around 9 or 10 servers in a month and I really don't want to insert user information all the time!

Hope you can help!

Regards Andreas Voss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. What you want is Coda's 'sites'. Set up each FTP server as a 'site' in coda, and you can save the server address, username and password in the site. So, to set up a new site:

1. open Coda
2. Coda should automatically open at the 'sites' page. If not, press Command-1 to go to sites
3. Right-click, and select 'add site'.
4. Fill out the details for the site, and save.

Whenever you open that site, Coda will automatically connect to the server.

It should be pretty self-explanatory once you see it, but let me know if you have any problems.